# Azure AD Cross-Subscription Federation for SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure subscription that hosts a VM with SQL Server Reporting Services. At the moment, the VM is just in a workgroup and I create users in the VM's local directory to grant permissions for access to SSRS. That is all working. What I need, now, is to be able to grant permissions to SSRS to users from a client's O365 or Azure AD subscription.

I assume I have to create a domain for my VM. It's a fairly light workload, so I would just use the single VM for all roles, including SSRS. Then, do I setup DirSync between my VM and the client's Azure AD/O365 directory?

Is there more to it than that? Will that scenario allow me to grant permissions to users from my Client's directory to the SSRS setup? Do I need to setup federation?

Edit:

From what I am reading, it seems that AAD Connect (or DirSync) is intended to sync users from a local AD to Office365 (AAD). What I need is to be able to sync users and passwords from an O365 subscription to a local AD hosted on a VM in Azure. Is this possible?

Comment: You should be able to use DirSync or ADConnect to achieve this. User writeback is no longer supported in Azure AD, so all of the permissions would still be granted from the VM's Active Directory.

Comment: Thanks, @MarileeTurscak-MSFT. I expect that I would supply permissions. What I want is for the users and passwords to sync across Azure subscriptions. Will DirSync and/or ADConnect do that?